What are the algebras of the powerset intersection (oplax) monad?
The assignment $X\mapsto\mathcal{P}(X)$ and $f\mapsto f_*$ (direct images) defines a functor $\mathcal{P}\colon\mathsf{Sets}\to\mathsf{Sets}$.
This functor has a monad structure whose multiplication $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X))\to\mathcal{P}(X)$is given by the union operation
$$\mathcal{U}\mapsto\bigcup_{U\in\mathcal{U}}U$$
and whose unit $X\to\mathcal{P}(X)$ is given by the map $x\mapsto\{x\}$, and the algebras for this monad are suplattices.
If we replace the union $\bigcup\colon\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X))$ with the intersection $\bigcap\colon\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X))$, we get an oplax monad in the 2-category of relations $\mathbf{Rel}$: left unitality holds on the nose, but associativity and right unitality only hold weakly (Clowder, Items 2, 3, and 4 of Proposition 2.3.7.1.2) in that we have
$$\bigcap_{A\in\mathcal{A}}\left(\bigcap_{U\in A}U\right)\subset\bigcap_{U\in\bigcap_{A\in\mathcal{A}}A}U$$
for each $\mathcal{A}\in\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X)))$ and
$$\bigcap_{\{x\}\in\chi_{X}(U)}\{x\}\subset U$$
for each $U\in\mathcal{P}(X)$.
The algebras for this oplax monad consist of pairs $(X,R)$ with $X$ a set and $R\colon\mathcal{P}(X)\to X$ a relation satisfying the following two conditions:

For each $x\in X$, we have $R(\{x\})=\{x\}$.
For each $\mathcal{U}\in\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X))$, we have $R(\bigcap_{U\in\mathcal{U}}U)=R(\{R(U)\ \mid\ U\in\mathcal{U}\})$.

Similarly, lax algebras satisfy $x\in R(\{x\})$ and $R(\bigcap_{U\in\mathcal{U}}U)\subset R(\{R(U)\ \mid|\ U\in\mathcal{U}\})$ while oplax algebras satisfy $R(\{x\})\subset\{x\}$ and $R(\{R(U)\ \mid|\ U\in\mathcal{U}\})\subset R(\bigcap_{U\in\mathcal{U}}U)$.
Question. Is there a nice characterisation of the (op/lax) algebras of this powerset intersection oplax monad, similarly to the characterisation of algebras of the powerset monad as suplattices?
(I'd also be interested in characterisations of special classes of such algebras, such as e.g. those where $R$ is a function.)
